# How to split money between the site owner and the vendor

Tags: 8, commerce

It have complete multi vendor system with each vendor registering and adding products(Drupal8+commerce). The total sell amount was to be splitted between the site admin and the vendor account. Admin should have right to set commision(Globally 20% commision amount I have imposed on each vendor) also admin can change the commision amount for specific vendor.

The main feature I needed to implement was the money splitting between the site owner and the vendor.

Users can checkout and buy products, typically from multiple vendors at one go. Upon successful checkout and payment, the entire payment is to be taken into the site admin’s account. Then from the total account, each merchant’s sales amount is calculated (as per products that has been checked out) and then from that site admin’s sales commission is calculated. Rest, will be paid to the vendor after the deduction of the site’s commission.

If the order value of the product is 100rs then site owner must have 20rs and vendor 80rs.

Any idea about how to proceed with it?

Comment: it's an idea, make a content type 'admin_orders', here add an entity-ref field to order, create a new rule, create admin_orders node on checkout event, in content type add relations to owner and vendor, $money fields, ..... and make any calculatios by rules, in other words, admin money in a separate content type, look for business-rules module

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at affiliate systems to see if they can guide you in the direction of a solution, e.g. https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_affiliate. The issue here is that you haven't defined what your actual end goal is - if you simply want to know what the 80/20 split of the sale value is, you can just use https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field. Do you want to add the split values up? Maybe use the Computed Field module, and a view? Or is the intention to automate the payouts to each party? Because that is a whole different story...

Comment: the module link you have provided above is for drupal 7 not drupal 8

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: After reading your updated post, it just sounds like you need to get into the weeds with some custom code here. A module that runs on cron that grabs all the completed orders that haven't yet been paid out, you can do this with a view programmatically. Then, loop over each order, calculate the appropriate payout, and then do whatever it is you want to do to distribute the funds - store the details for an admin to manually resolve, connect to some sort of payment system, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's on the plan. I am waiting for some customer to request this feature: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_marketplace/issues/3017762